# when performing dataframe.to_excel, the order of values is changed

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, type and value. The type is the label, and this one is not ordered alphabetically which is fine and that is the expected output. it should not be alphabetically ordered, it has a custom order.

but when I do a df.to_excel() command, the output shows that the type column became alphabetically ordered. I'm not sure how this happens.

I used pdb to check the values while the code is running and I see that the df shows the expected order. But when it outputs the file, the sorting is changed.

sample input:

```
type value
d    4
e    5
a    1
c    3
b    2
```

sample output:

```
type value
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
```

Comment: Could you provide sample input/output that reproduces this?

Comment: what is `pdb` ?

Comment: @MaxU it is python debugger

Comment: @JonClements I have updated the question with sample input and output. sorry I can't provide the actual values but that is what's happening when I execute a to_excel function

Comment: @niccolom. and do you get the same if you try and write that data as you've posted? Are there any other operations on the dataframe apart from a literal `df.to_excel(...)` ?

Comment: @JonClements, yes, first I read an excel file, then pivot it and use aggfunc np.median. then I merge it with df2, which holds that proper sort of the type column.

Comment: @niccolom. If you do a `df.head(20)` or whatever immediately before writing out the dataframe - what does that show? For instance - `merge` may re-order the resultant dataframe depending on the `how` and `sort` options...

Comment: hi Jon, I'm sorry for wasting your time I got confused. I was outputting the first DF, but it should be the 2nd DF that I need to output to excel

Comment: @niccolom., `pivot` sorts the data set...